# RST, ACK from 216.98.48.133 without any SYN from me? For real? How? Why?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I am trying to figure out why I always get 
"The Ubisoft server is not available at the time. Please try again later."
Apparently, the server is actually up and running, so it seems the problem is on my side.

I used Wireshark to capture the network traffic.
I am no network expert, but I have understood that the usual handshake is
[SYN] - [SYN,ACK] - [ACK]
What I am seeing in the Wireshark capture however, is that the remote server is..
.."suddenly" sending 3 [RST, ACK] packets, at 500 ms intervals
- without my side ever sending anything to that IP address.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]
[Click to see a screenshot separate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ6zG.png)

Packet 1: My PC (WINULTX; 10.0.0.3) asks (resolver1.opendns.com; 208.67.222.222)
what is the IP address of **gconnect.ubi.com**

Packet 2: DNS server replies that **gconnect.ubi.com** is **CNAME** for **lb-onl-vh-wspub01.ubisoft.com**, and that **lb-onl-vh-wspub01.ubisoft.com** has IP address **216.98.48.133**

Packet 3: **216.98.48.133, tcp/80** "suddenly" sends a 54 byte **[RST, ACK]** packet to my PC at **tcp/27939**

Packet 4: My PC at **tcp/23632** sends a 55 byte **[ACK]** packet to **216.98.48.69, tcp/14000** ( - the DNS server has earlier told my PC that **lb-upc-dmx.ubisoft.com** has the IP address **216.98.48.69**)

Packet 5: A 100% copy of Packet 3, sent 500 ms later

Packet 6:  **216.98.48.69, tcp/14000** replies with a 55 byte **[ACK]** packet to my PC at **tcp/23632**

Packet 7: A 100% copy of Packet 3, sent 500 ms later

Packet 8 -> Packet 22: My PC at **tcp/23632** continues to talk with **216.98.48.69, tcp/14000**

I have some questions regarding this.
First, is it possible that there are some packets missing here?
I find it very strange that, my PC first wants to know the IP address of **gconnect.ubi.com**,
but then, after learning that it is a **CNAME** for **lb-onl-vh-wspub01.ubisoft.com**,
 and that **lb-onl-vh-wspub01.ubisoft.com** has IP address **216.98.48.133**
- it does not do anything..?
Instead, 3 packets from that very IP address is suddenly sent to my PC..?!
Is it possible that Wireshark missed some packets sent from my PC to that IP address,
and if so - how could that happen?

In the case that there is **not** any packets missed by Wireshark..
- how is it possible that **216.98.48.133** started to send those packets?
And why did it do that..?

---

Additional info:

The "3 [RST, ACK] packets, at 500 ms intervals" situation repeats itself later in the capture. This corresponds to when I manually clicked "Additional content" in the game. What differs, is that my PC now wanted to know the IP address of **onlineconfigservice.ubi.com**
However, **onlineconfigservice.ubi.com** is **also** a CNAME for **lb-onl-vh-wspub01.ubisoft.com**, meaning there is the exact same IP address; **216.98.48.133**

[image: Wireshark screenshot]
[Click to see a screenshot in separate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ6es.png)

I have Windows 7 SP1, with Teredo IPv6 disabled.

I am not 100% sure that Ubisofts server "are up", but there is no information on their Twitter page that it "is down" - so that is why I assume there is a problem on my end.

Even though I have played PC games before, this is the first time I am trying to get a multi-player game to work. All the earlier games I have played have been completely offline.

The game in question is Assassin's Creed III. I start Uplay, then choose Assassin's Creed III, Play single-player, then at the menu, I choose Extras. There are 3 options after that; all of them requires a connection to the Ubisoft server, all of them gives the same result.

The tips and fixes on the Ubisoft forums are ..strange. Somehow, the "make sure your firewall lets you connect to a server on [the server's] port 80 and 443" have become "make sure you set up your router NAT to forward incoming packets on ports 80 and 443 to your PC". And this misinterpretation is repeated over and over, without anyone noticing it is a bit strange to do this when there are no server at either port 80 or 443 on your PC.

I have tried to use my normal browser, Mozilla Firefox 28.0, and entering the URLs;
**gconnect.ubi.com** and **onlineconfigservice.ubi.com** both gives a 403 Server error message.
While **lb-gconnect.ubisoft.com** (which is yet another CNAME for **lb-onl-vh-wspub01.ubisoft.com**),
**lb-onl-vh-wspub01.ubisoft.com** itself, and also when entering the IP address directly - **216.98.48.133**
- these 3 gives me a simple "OK" message.
Most importantly - there is a normal handshake [SYN] - [SYN,ACK] - [ACK] for each of these 5 URLs.
So this is a kind of evidence that there is a server at **216.98.48.133**, listening at TCP port 80.